# How would I save textfield for a specific date?

Tags: ios, swift

Im making a weight loss app that saves how much you weight each day. I need to know how to save the weight for the current date and then making the text field empty for the next day. I saved the textfield using NSUserDefault. Im trying to do what the other fitness apps have for there UI where you could go look at previous days and see the saved data. Can someone point me in the right direction. Thanks!

```
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    let stringKey = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    textFieldWeight.text = stringKey.stringForKey("saveWeight")

    addTextFieldForWeight()


    }

    func addTextFieldForWeight() {

    textFieldWeight.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.Line
    textFieldWeight.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    textFieldWeight.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionType.Yes
    textFieldWeight.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumberPad
    textFieldWeight.delegate = self
    textFieldWeight.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    textFieldWeight.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Done
    textFieldWeight.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignment.Center
    self.view?.addSubview(textFieldWeight)
    }



    override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {





        if node.name == "next" {

        let nextDay = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitDay,value: 1,toDate:
            NSDate(),options: nil)
        let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
        formatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.FullStyle



        let dateString = formatter.stringFromDate(nextDay!)
        dateLabel.text = String(dateString)

    }







    if node.name == "before" {

        let earlyDate = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitDay,value: -1,toDate:
            NSDate(),options: NSCalendarOptions.WrapComponents)
        let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
        formatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.FullStyle



        let dateString = formatter.stringFromDate(earlyDate!)
        dateLabel.text = String(dateString)

        }
           }
```

Comment: Do you need to save the every days history ? i mean each and every days weight.

Comment: yes I might change it to calories instead of the weight but I want to save every day.

Comment: For that you must use [sqlite](http://www.appcoda.com/sqlite-database-ios-app-tutorial/) or [core Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html)

Comment: What's wrong with your posted code (besides "it doesn't do what I want it to do")? Can you tailor your question to focus on your attempt and fixing it?

Comment: Yes the date when I press the button to go back only goes back one day and when I press the button to go forward it goes two days in front. Also I want to be able to save the UITextField for the current date and then create an empty UITextField for the next day and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look at a Core Data structure or else create a class for your data objects that you can archive.  It's a lot to explain in a little box like this, but look up Core Data and Creating and Extracting Archives on Apple's help documentation.

If you want a simpler solution, try just using an NSMutableArray where each element in the array can be a custom object which contains an NSDate and NSNumber object for the weight.  You can then save this array to NSUserDefaults. Your custom object will have to be archivible, however.